# Javascript / jQuery .load loading multiple files into div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to load some contents of a file into a div:

```
$('#mydiv').load('template1.html');
```

Is it possible to load multiple into multiple div's?

For example:

```
$('#mydiv', '#mydiv2').load('template1.html', 'template2.html');
```

If so how?

Comment: No, you can't. Period.

Comment: No ways around it then?

Comment: You can write a function which will do this. Natively not possible.

Comment: @Vohuman You can't using the `$.load()` function, coz it supports only one URL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know that. But one _can_ do this. We don't have to use the `$.fn.load` function.

Comment: @Vohuman This question is related to `$.load()` so you can't do using it, and yes, you can change the code like how I did. Hope you understood what I meant.

Comment: @Vohuman Read well: *Javascript / jQuery **.load** loading multiple files into div's*, and not using any other way.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  "and not using any other way"? Okay, that's your interpretation. Ironically your answer shows that it's possible. The point was that. You used the "period" before thinking twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), no. You can't.

But if you would like to *automate it*, you can do using an associative object may be? This is just a try:

```
ajaxLoads = {
    "#div1": "template1.html",
    "#div2": "template2.html",
    "#div3": "template3.html",
    "#div4": "template4.html",
    "#div5": "template5.html"
}
$.each(ajaxLoads, function (div, url) {
    $(div).load(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using jQuery:

```
let pages = [
    'page1.html', 
    'page2.html'
];

$.each(pages, function(_key, value) {
    $.get(value, {}, function(result) { 
        let $html = $('<div />').html(result); 
        $('#mydiv').append($html); 
    },'html');
});
```

Comment: Note: in this case, multiple html files are appended to the same div.